# Returning from doInBackground() for AsyncTask brings me to AsyncTask.class

Tags: android

I ran the debugging by placing a break point on a line of code in my doInBackground(). I kept clicking step over. Then, on the line of the return statement. I clicked step over. Android Studio opened AsynTask.class and brought me to the last line of the class. Why?

I couldn't include the return statement in my try-catch block, or otherwise the function will have no return statement.

There is no error. But the function is returning Null.

```
@Override
protected List<GridViewItem> doInBackground(String... path){
    List<GridViewItem> items = new ArrayList<GridViewItem>();

    // List all the items within the folder.
    File[] files = new File(path[0]).listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        final File file = files[i];
        // Add the directories containing images or sub-directories
        if (file.isDirectory()
                && file.listFiles(new ImageFileFilter()).length > 0) {
            items.add(new GridViewItem(file.getAbsolutePath(), true, null, false, i));
        }
        // Add the images
        else {
            Bitmap image = BitmapHelper.decodeBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),
                    50,
                    50);

            items.add(new GridViewItem(file.getAbsolutePath(), false, image, false, i));
        }
    }
    return items;
 }
```

Comment: It's very unlikely that this is returning `null`, since you always instantiate `items` and always return `items`. I could believe that it is returning an _empty_ list, if `File[] files` is empty. I could also believe that it is throwing an exception, since you seem to think that any non-directory file is always a bitmap, and maybe your directory has non-bitmap, non-directory files in it.

Comment: There is only 1 photo in the folder. When this block of code was placed and executed in MainActivity.java, it worked. I checked when debugging that files is not empty. It may throw an exception. But how do I know what the exception is? I can't put return in try{}